# How do I make raycast hit with a canvas element(screen space overlay)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

For some reason, my 2D Overlay is not reacting to the raycast hit while the 3D objects work fine. I've searched the internet for quite some time now and I still can't find a solution to it. (I'm kinda new-ish to both C# and Unity so my knowledge is limited)

If anyone can shed some light on this issue I have, it will be greatly appreciated!

The issue here is that I would want my cursor to display a console message when I click on the 2D Overlay. The 3D Objects work and displayed the relevant message in the console but for some reason, the 2D graphic isn't detecting the raycast hit.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;

public class rayCast_Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject TutorialUI;

    public Canvas gameChara2D;
    [SerializeField]
    private float rayCastDistance = 25f;
    [SerializeField]
    float DistanceFromCamera = 1f;

    private ARRaycastManager aRRaycastManager;
    private Vector3 touchPos;
    private Vector3 touchOrigin;



    private bool onTouchHold = false;

    private RaycastHit hitObject;



    private void Awake()
    {
        aRRaycastManager = FindObjectOfType<ARRaycastManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            touchPos = Input.mousePosition;

            if (!onTouchHold)
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos);


                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitObject, rayCastDistance))
                {
                    if(hitObject.transform.CompareTag("Moveable"))
                    {
                        onTouchHold = true;
                        touchOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
                        Debug.Log("Hello. This is a 3D object");
                    }
                }

                if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitObject, rayCastDistance))
                {
                    if (hitObject.transform.CompareTag("ChallengeUI"))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Hello. This is a 2D object");
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            onTouchHold = false;
        }


    }
}
```

[image: Scene Tree]
[image: Canvas Properties]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use a `Physics.Raycast` for UI elements nor 2D colliders.

In general what you want to hit is rather a specific [`Graphic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html) component such as an [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) or [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component with [`RaycastTarget`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-raycastTarget.html) enabled.

---

If you want to hit a `BoxCollider2D` you'll have to use the [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) instead. However this is not used to raycast in the `Z` direction but only works for hitting the collider from the side via an XY direction.

---

For actually hitting UI you have to use a different type of Raycast not going through Physics but using an [`EventSystem.RaycastAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.RaycastAll.html) like e.g.

```
var pointerEventData = new pointerEventData{ position = touchPos};
var raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();
EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerEventData, raycastResults);

if(raycastResults.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var result in RaycastResults)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Note further that you have a check for tag `ChallangeUI` but your UI object has layer `UI`.